# How to tell when a computer is idle?

Tags: debian, administration

I have a computer that is only used some of the time, and I was was wondering if there was a way to have it turn itself off after a period of inactivity.

Here's the tricky part, if I was just thinking about having it turn itself off *when the GUI is idle* then I think it would be significantly easier, but I'm trying to make sure I don't cut anyone off who is actively using the machine via SSH as well.  The computer in question is Debian 5.0.

Is there a way of detecting if the machine is idle, as in nobody using the GUI and nobody is using the machine via SSH?  If an SSH connection is open, but is not actively being used, then the computer should consider that idle.

Comment: Should this be moved to stackoverflow maybe?

Comment: the question isn't particularly programming-ish, and there might be suitable answers which aren't either.

Comment: A friend suggested DBUS, but in my brief 5 minutes of googling it didn't look like it would pay any attention to ssh connections, idle or not. I'd would be nice if I was uninformed though.. need to keep looking when I wake up.

Comment: Why would you want to shutdown a Linux computer anyway? :-)

Comment: @amphetamachine Power saving.  Reducing thermal output in a large cluster room.  We have two Linux clusters where I work; one 69 machines, another 43: enabling power management has made a measurable difference to the heat of the rooms (which were too hot) and the electricity bill.

Comment: Why would I want to shutdown a computer that is rarely used? Heat, power savings, noise polution (it's an old machine), security, and the obvious 'why have it on if nobody is using it' argument.  If it was my desktop computer, it would stay on, but this machine is only used occasionally and I don't need a space-heater.

Answer (score 2):

```
who -q
```

Will show who, and how many users have an open tty (i.e. at console, via X, ssh, telent) but will not show users connecting via pop, http etc

Comment: Is there a way of telling of telling what the last command they ran was (PID, to check if it's still running) and when it was executed? Do you think that could be accomplished with some changes to the bash prompt?

Comment: You'd need to be a lot more specific about what you mean. What if they started a setsid progam before logging out - would you consider their session still active? What can you not get from the bash history?

Answer (score 1):

`gdm` / `gnome-power-manager` can detect this and suspend the machine appropriately.  for GNOME2 Try

```
gconftool-2 --direct --config-source=xml:readwrite:/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.defaults -s --type=int /apps/gnome-power-manager/timeout/sleep_computer_ac 600
```

and

```
gconftool-2 --direct --config-source=xml:readwrite:/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.defaults -s --type=int /apps/gnome-power-manager/timeout/sleep_computer_ac 600
```

as root.  You may need to restart `gdm` for the settings to take effect. (the number is seconds so 600 is 10 minutes).

under GNOME3, there is a similar pair of `gsettings` keys (the above silently fails).

If you aren't running GNOME,  you could inspect the source of `gnome-power-manager` to figure out how it establishes idle-ness.

Comment: `gdm / gnome-power-manager` can detect idle ssh connections?

Comment: idle ones? No. Active ones? I believe so.  Your question suggested  you didn't want to cut off people using the machine via ssh *actively*.  If you don't want them to suspend even with idle ssh connections, please revise your question.

Comment: Actually that sounds like exactly what I want! I'll be checking that out, thank you! Once I've verified that it will work for my purposes I'll choose your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Try command [xprintidle](http://freecode.com/projects/xprintidle?branch_id=61675&release_id=212408) to get idle time in milliseconds.